# Oauth2 Yahoo Gemini API

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am having trouble calling Yahoo Gemini API to access Yahoo Gemini Advertising from my C# console (desktop) application.

Here are steps I used:

1. Create an installed application on `https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/`.  This gave me both `{Client ID}` and `{Client Secret}`.
2. `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id={Client ID} &redirect_uri=oob&response_type=code&language=en-us`.  This will take me to the yahoo login screen where I sign in.  Press the Agree button and the next screen shows the seven-letter authorization code (say nzbcns9).  I write down this authorization code.
3. Then I use the following code to try to get the access token:

   ```
   class Program
   {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string clientId = {Client ID};
       string secret = {Client Secret};

       var request = WebRequest.Create(@"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token");
       request.Method = "POST";

       SetBasicAuthHeader(request, clientId, secret);

       string postData = "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=oob&code=nzbcns9";
       ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
       byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
       request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
       Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
       dataStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
       dataStream.Close();

       request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
       var response = request.GetResponse();
       Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
   }

   static void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
   {
       string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
       authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
       request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
   }
   }
   ```

Then I get

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse().

What did I do  wrong?

I also try to post the same message using Fiddler, I get

> {"error":"invalid_request"}

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and what worked for me was to put the line `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` BEFORE `Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();`

So this worked:

```
    string postData = "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=oob&code=nzbcns9";
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Has the API changed, or am I missing something?  With the above code, I get:

  The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these worked for me, but it did work once I changed the SetBasicAuthHeader to use ISO-8859-1 encoding:

```
    static void SetBasicAuthHeader( WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword )
    {
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String( Encoding.GetEncoding( "ISO-8859-1" ).GetBytes( authInfo ) );
        request.Headers[ "Authorization" ] = "Basic " + authInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Note that this will get you a refresh token.  The auth code will expire after each use, so save the refresh token and use that as a starting point for your app.